# Visual studio installer project doesn't run installer class

Tags: c#, .net, ieaddon

I have an ie extension with two installers, one for 64 bits and one for 32. After days of trial and error with the installer not properly registering the extension, I found out that the 32 bit installer is not running my installer class, while the 64 bits one is.

The settings are strictly the same on both. Specifically, InstallClass is set to true on all custom actions.

I finally discovered that by putting a division by zero on the install method. I get the error on the 64 bits one, but the 32 bit doesn't seem to run the installer. Any clues on the cause for this?

I am using vs 2017 enterprise, on which I had to install an extension for Visual Studio Installer projects. The extension targets Framework 4 Client Profile.

Comment: "while the 64 bits one is."  is the project containing the class 64bit by any chance?

Comment: The project is build on the appropriate platform, the 64 bits installer gets the 64 build, the 32 a 32 build. The project is working if I do the .dll registration manually, so that is ok. Only problem is the install class not being run on the 32 bits one.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the 32 bit installer run the install class, the method was quite simple, but I have no understanding of the cause effect relationship. All I did was removing the dll from the gac (which was added when I registered it manually):

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /u "extension.dll"

For some reason, when the assembly was on the gac, the installer wasn't run. I can only guess that a previous version was there, so my exception throwing on the installer was never applied. That would mean that the installer class was indeed run, just not on the dll I was installing at the time, but the one one the gac.

Comment: I not accepting this answer for now, as it doesn't really explain much of what was happening, but those experiencing this issue can solve it this way.